# Error when execute action button from Adaptive Card

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, microsoft-teams-js

We have Microsoft Teams Bot and send Adaptive Cards to users.
One user received "this card action is disabled because you've blocked" after trying to click on Action Button.

Why do we receive this error, and how can we fix it?

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIIGv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Navigate to MS Teams Admin centre (https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/)
2. Enable sideloading and external apps
3. Restart Teams

There might be chances of this app being blocked by Admin. So, it's better to try that out by contacting with your admin.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-teams-overview#external-apps